# Determine which DateTimePattern pattern was used joda

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

If I have code such as this:

```
DateTimeParser[] parsers = {
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMM").getParser(),
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd").getParser(),
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmm").getParser(),
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmZ").getParser(),
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSSSZ").getParser()
};

DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append(null, parsers).toFormatter();

final DateTime dateTime = formatter
        .parseDateTime(dateString);

return new Timestamp(dateTime.getMillis());
```

How can I determine which pattern was used? I want to force UTC timezone only in situation when no timezone is explicitly provided. ie, when Z is missing

Alternatively, how can I simply determine if a timezone was provided when parsing a joda datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always get the zone from the code below  with [withOffsetParsed()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withOffsetParsed()) and compare with your default zone

```
String dateString = "2016052914346.2354+0300";
DateTimeParser[] parsers = {DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMM").getParser(),DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSSSZ").getParser()};
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append(null, parsers).toFormatter();
DateTime dateTime = formatter.withOffsetParsed().parseDateTime(dateString);
DateTimeZone zone = dateTime.getZone();//+03.00
```